# Getting error while using pdfutil in soapUi free version in CompareMode

Tags: pdf, open-source, soapui

I wanted to compare 2 pdf using PDFUtil with CompareMode but i am getting the below error.

```
 Wed Jan 17 15:25:30 CET 2018:ERROR:An error occurred [No such property: 
 compareMode for class: Script13], see error log for details
```

The below is my code in soapUI Groovy Script section.

```
 import com.testautomationguru.utility.PDFUtil;

 PDFUtil pdfUtil = new PDFUtil();
 String file1="C:/SoapOutPut/ENV1/TEST_DATA1.pdf";
 String file2="C:/SoapOutPut/ENV1/TEST_DATA12.pdf";

 pdfUtil.setCompareMode(CompareMode.VISUAL_MODE);

 pdfUtil.highlightPdfDifference(true);
 pdfUtil.setImageDestinationPath("c:/output/file");
 pdfUtil.compare(file1, file2);
```

Can any one help me to solve this problems. or what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I think it is complaining about CompareMode, try adding import com.testautomationguru.utility.CompareMode; (source: https://github.com/vinsguru/pdf-util)

Comment: Thanks you so much.. i added  import com.testautomationguru.utility.CompareMode;  in my program and started working.